# Pytorch installation problems with Anaconda

Tags: pyqt, anaconda, pytorch

After having upgraded my environment's python to Python 3.61, I attempted to install pytorch using this command:

conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch

However I got this error:

Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

-pytorch
-pyqt

I also used the commands
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda90
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda80

But the result is still the same. Anyone got a clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved after downgrading from Python 3.6.2 to Python 3.5.1 after running:

```
conda install -c anaconda python=3.5.1
```

After running this command, run:

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch
```

Pytorch should install as per normal. A similar issue occurs for openCV as well

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to install pytorch using anaconda is

1. conda create -n py_env python=3.5
2. source activate py_env
3. conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision -c pytorch
4. Go to python shell and import using the command

   *import torch*

Hope this helps.